# how to define the type of prop of the styled component of material UI?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, material-ui, styled-components

I am new to the typescript so go easy on me. I am working with a react project using typescript. while doing so I have faced an issue when I was trying to configure a component of material UI using styled components. I am unable to define a type for the prop which I pass for the styled component.

as a reference use the code below

```
const DarkLightSwitch = styled(Switch)(({ theme }) => ({
...
})
```

the component contains the styles which I intend to make to the switch component. Inside this I have used the `theme.palette.mode`

it would be a big help if anyone clarifies this for me.

I have tried declaring a type for the component like

```
type InputProp = { theme: { palette: { mode: string } } };
const DarkLightSwitch = styled(Switch)<InputProp>(({ theme }) => ({
...
})
```

when I do this I have to explicitly provide the component with the theme myself. which i think is not the expected behavior.

And I have also tried doing this

```
type InputProp = { theme: { palette: { mode: string } } };
const DarkLightSwitch = styled(Switch)((prop: InputProp) => ({
...
})
```

this also resulted in the same.
Don't mind these approaches if they are fundamentally wrong .